# Has_one :through polymorphic belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I have a Tagging model, with polymorphic associations to tags and taggable items. Taggable items all have an association to a feed_item (has_one :feed_item). I want to associate the tagging to the feed_item ie in tagging.rb

```
   belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
   belongs_to :tag, :polymorphic => true

   has_one :feed_item, :through => :taggable
```

This has_one association doesn't work. For example in console Tagging.first.feed_item leads to the error

```
 NameError: uninitialized constant Tagging::Taggable
```

Any advice to how one sets up this sort of association?

For background, the following is an example of a taggable object's model:

```
 has_one :feed_item, :as => :item
```

IE: A tagging has_one taggable object which has_one feed_item.

Comment: What is being called to produce that error?

Comment: You can't has_one through a belongs_to.

Comment: sure you can they do it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556322/belongs-to-has-one-structure

Comment: see the answer, with "player", which belongs to a team, and has a has_one association through to a club

Comment: Does `Tagging.first.taggable` return the taggable item? If so, does it respond to `feed_item`?

Comment: yes Tagging.first.taggable.feed_item works great

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
has_one :feed_item, :through => :taggable
```

with this:

```
def feed_item
  self.taggable.feed_item
end
```

Now you can call `@taggable.feed_item` and it'll work.

Comment: that method will work.. but I don't think it's really an association. I say this because in the great picture I want to associate through this association too. For example, if I have an Article with many Taggings, and I now want to associate the Article to has_many :feed_items, :through => :tagging.. then this won't recognize the method above as an association. (ie Article.feed_items error says no :feed_item association exists on Tagging model).

Comment: What?? Does `FeedItem` belong to `Tagging` itself or to the taggable object (`Article`, etc...)? Post the associations in `feed_item.rb` please.

Comment: @gg_s FeedItem belongs to TaggableObject (OP edited the post)

Comment: Another thing. If an article had many taggings, each of those taggings would have a feed_item derived from its associated taggable object (the article). In practice, such an association would always echo back the article's own feed_item. It's a circular reference and it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look at https://github.com/rahul/SO_9288016 and let me know if it does not work for you.

I also added a tiny db/development.sqlite3

Comment: hey Rahul, thanks for the help. The app you created looks fine, but a Tagging still has no association to feed_item. ie you can't write Tagging.first.feed_item, unless I am mistaken. Right?

Comment: "Article to has_many :feed_items, :through => :tagging" - how is this possible when because TaggingableObject already :has_one :feed_item?